# SQL Server - Memory quota error during migration to in-memory table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, in-memory, in-memory-tables

We are currently migrating to in-memory tables on SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition. The disk based table is 55GB data + 54Gb of indexes (71M records). RAM is 900 GB. But during data migration (INSERT statement) we get an error message:

> Msg 41823, Level 16, State 109, Line 150
> Could not perform the operation because the database has reached its quota for in-memory tables. This error may be transient. Please retry the operation.

The in-memory file is “unlimited”, so it looks strange since SQL Server 2019 should not have any size restrictions for in-memory tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think in-memory data size in a single mem-opt table is unlimited on standard edition?

From [Memory Limits in SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/12/sql-server-2016/memory-limits-sp1) (all of which still applies according to [2019 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15)):

> Each user database on the instance can have an additional 32GB allocated to memory-optimized tables, over and above the buffer pool limit.

So, you can do what you want, I suppose, but you'll have to spread it across multiple databases. You won't be able to store more than 32GB in a single mem-opt table or even in multiple mem-opt tables in a single database.

Cropped and probably inappropriately-scaled screenshot from [the 2019 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15):

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! This is my fault. I just paid my attention to a general sentence on one blog: "The maximum size of memory recommended by Microsoft to store the durable Memory-Optimized tables, that will be used during the recovery process, is increased in SQL Server 2016 to be 2 TB, instead of the 256 GB recommendation in SQL Server 2014."